# SUM values depending on another column value and exclude certain column values MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to SUM up the values of 3 pay grades (ordinary, overtime 1.5 and overtime 2.0) and then work out whether 'ordinary' is equal to 8, and if so, have a calculation of (the SUM-0.4)/7.6. If not, then it is just (the SUM/7.6)... This is so I can calculate headcounts for employees at full time equivalent.

So here is where I am at the moment. The values don't seem to be adding up to what I calculate manually, I think my process is wrong:

```
SELECT Supervisor,
SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(workdate) = 2 THEN IF(employeehours.paycode = '01 Ordinary' AND employeehours = 8,((employeehours-0.4)/7.6),(employeehours/7.6)) END) `Monday`,
SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(workdate) = 3 THEN IF(employeehours.paycode = '01 Ordinary' AND employeehours = 8,((employeehours-0.4)/7.6),(employeehours/7.6)) END) `Tuesday`,
SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(workdate) = 4 THEN IF(employeehours.paycode = '01 Ordinary' AND employeehours = 8,((employeehours-0.4)/7.6),(employeehours/7.6)) END) `Wednesday`,
SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(workdate) = 5 THEN IF(employeehours.paycode = '01 Ordinary' AND employeehours = 8,((employeehours-0.4)/7.6),(employeehours/7.6)) END) `Thursday`,
SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(workdate) = 6 THEN IF(employeehours.paycode = '01 Ordinary' AND employeehours = 8,((employeehours-0.4)/7.6),(employeehours/7.6)) END) `Friday`,
SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(workdate) = 7 THEN IF(employeehours.paycode = '01 Ordinary' AND employeehours = 8,((employeehours-0.4)/7.6),(employeehours/7.6)) END) `Saturday`
FROM payroll.employeedatanew_copy
JOIN payroll.employeehours ON employeedatanew_copy.`ID Number` = employeehours.employeeid
WHERE employeehours.workdate BETWEEN '2013-12-02' AND '2013-12-07'
GROUP BY supervisor
```

Comment: There's an awful lot going on there.  I don't know that anyone can tell you what's wrong without lots more information.  I would suggest breaking it down into much smaller chunks.  See if your `IF` statement is working correctly, without the sum and the case, and then build it up from there.

Comment: Do you want to sum the overtime hours at a higher rate than the ordinary hours?

Comment: I worked it out after listening to Andrew :) See below. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Still not working correctly....